# Add user to Lotus Domino using esb (wso2)

Tags: wso2, lotus-domino

we are evaluating to add an esb to our organization to solve several problems.
One of these problems is this: we need to add an user that must be created only on a custom hrm software to Domino Mail.
Before starting we would like to understand if this thing is possible using WSO2 ESB.
In addition to this is very important for us to understand there is a connector/adapter ready or we need to do custom Lotus script programming on Domino side.
Thanks in advance,
Mario

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the available WSO2 ESB connectors and other connectors in [WSO2 Store](http://store.wso2.com/). It looks like there is no connector for Lotus Domino at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for confirming this. We now are evaluating using ldap to add users to Domino.